# Solving the functional equation $f(xf(x)+yf(y))=xy$ over positive reals

Tags: functional-equations

Does there exist any function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all positive real numbers $x,y$ the following is true :
$$f(xf(x)+yf(y))=xy$$

Comment: $x (f(x ) + f'(x)) = C$

Comment: f need not be differentiable. If you claim it is differentiable please prove it.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1445131